# Add element to JFrame from other class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have two classes in one `JFrame` creation:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    public void createWindow() throws IOException {
        setTitle(GeneralValues.PROGRAM_NAME);
        setSize(1100, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

And in the second I have a `JLabel`:

```
public class InitialConfiguration {

    Window w = new Window();

    public void main() {
        JLabel blauncherIcon = new JLabel();
        blauncherIcon.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
        blauncherIcon.setOpaque(true);
        blauncherIcon.setText("Text");

        w.add(blauncherIcon);
    }
}
```

My main method:

```
public class Main {

    Window w = new Window();
    InitialConfiguration ic = new InitialConfiguration();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
         w.createWindow();
         ic.main();
    
    }

}
```

I wanted to add a label from the `InitialConfiguration` class to the frame from the `Window` class but unfortunately this code creates a frame but does not add the label from the `InitialConfiguration` class. Can it be done at all?

Comment: 1) Is the method in `InitialConfiguration` your actual `main` method? Because if so, its declaration is incorrect and this code won't even run. If it is not, then you should rename that method. 2) "this code creates a JFrame", does it though? I don't see you ever call `setVisible()` on the frame anywhere... 3) You don't call `createWindow()`, only your constructor of `Window()`.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB. 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 3) See also..

Comment: .. [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) 4) ` Window w = new Window();` Don't name a class `Window` as it is the same name as an AWT class. Give it a **descriptive** name.

Comment: @maloomeister this method main is not my main method and I know that if it was, the program would not even start, I have another main method and it is the main method that first calls createWindow in Window and then main in InitialConfiguration. Since my code was too big to paste here, I cut some Window class and didn't notice that I cut setVisible(true)but it actually is.

Comment: @KrystianWiecheć then please show us your main method aswell. Also please make sure to also take note of Andrew Thompsons comments, when further working on your project.

Comment: I notice that you set the LayoutManager to null. This is a **very** bad idea. It may seem good in a trivial case, but LayoutManager's exist to help the developer. Sooner or later you will want to run a program on a system that is different from the one you're testing on, and those null layout managers will bit you in the back end. Trust me, they are relatively easy to learn and use, compared to the alternative

Comment: I added my main method to the question

Answer (score 0):

You didn't start the Jframe at window class and I don't know your main class so I made it for your understanding. Check this codes;

(**Edited**)

Main: Example code:

```
public class MainMenu{

   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Windows w = new Windows();
        InitialConfiguration ini = new InitialConfiguration(w);
        w.createWindow();
        ini.main();
    }
}
```

ICONFIG class example code:

```
public class InitialConfiguration {

    Window w;

    public InitialConfiguration(Windows w){
        this.w = w;
}
    public void main() {
        
        
        JLabel blauncherIcon = new JLabel();
        blauncherIcon.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100);
        blauncherIcon.setOpaque(true);
        blauncherIcon.setText("Text");

        w.add(blauncherIcon);
        w.repaint();
    }
}
```

Window class example code:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    public void createWindow(){
        setTitle("Your title");
        setSize(1100, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works but i want to call w.createWindow() from my main method.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is, that you went wrong with the instances of your `Window`. Your `InitialConfiguration` has a member variable of `Window`, to which the label is being added. But this is not the same instance of the `Window` that you have in your `Main` class.

So all in all, you create and show the window, but never show the second window you actually added your label to.

So altogether, if you really want to keep your structure this way (I would advise against that but you may have your reasons), passing the correct `Window` instance as a method parameter should fix it.

```
public class InitialConfiguration {

    // Removed second Window here
  
    public void main(Window w) { // rename this method please
        JLabel blauncherIcon = new JLabel();
        blauncherIcon.setBounds(100, 100, 100, 100); // use layout managers
        blauncherIcon.setOpaque(true);
        blauncherIcon.setText("Text");
        w.add(blauncherIcon);
    }
}
```

And your "Main":

```
public class Main {

    Window w = new Window(); // rename the class Window please
    InitialConfiguration ic = new InitialConfiguration();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
         w.createWindow();
         ic.main(w);
    }
}
```